# Making pedometer with accelerometer

Tags: arduino, sensor, signal-processing, accelerometer, algorithm

I want to make pedometer with ADXL345 and ARDUINO UNO board.  I am using ADXL345 with Full resolution

```
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // Start communicating with the device
  Wire.write(0x31);
  Wire.write(0x0B);
  Wire.endTransmission();
```

and

```
Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x2C);
  Wire.write(0x09); //For low power 000x x pin set to 1  /1001 determine Hz
  Wire.endTransmission();
```

According to datasheet,  I am using it with Output Data Rate = 50 and Bandwidth (Hz) =25 .

So data rate 20 ms I guess. When I checked the pedometer codes, they use like

```
delay(200);
delay(50);
```

How can I determine good delay ?

My codes full code here

```
void loop() {
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x32); // Start with register 0x32 (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  X_out = ( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8); // X-axis value
  X = X_out /256; //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 256, according to the datasheet
  Y_out = ( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8); // Y-axis value
  Y = Y_out /256;
  Z_out = ( Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8); // Z-axis value
  Z = Z_out /256;

  ave = sqrt((X - xave) * (X - xave) + (Y - yave) * (Y - yave) + (Z - zave) * (Z - zave));//  ave = sqrt(x*x + y*y +z*z); 

  if(sampling == 0)
  {
    maxave = ave;
    minave = ave;
  }

  else if(maxave < ave)
  {
    maxave = ave;
  }

  else if(minave > ave)
  {
    minave = ave;
  }

  sampling++;

  if(sampling >= 20)
  {
    threshold = (maxave + minave) / 2 + 0.3;
    sampling = 0;
  }
delay(200);
```

[image]

Red line = threshold value and blue line steps of mine. I made 14 steps in this graph. If we count the peak values, it is equal 16 I guess.

```
threshold = (maxave + minave) / 2 + 0.3;
```

As you can see, I am using a fixed value (0.3). How can I make this dynamic ? If I don't choose a fixed value, anyone can use it.

How can I find the differential
value in each of three axes Xdiff Ydiff Zdiff . I read the articles and they found this value.

Comment: As this seems mostly code based and exclusively Arduino, it might be better suited to the Arduino SE or Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Nyquist" criterion states that you can recreate a signal by sampling at twice the frequency of the highest frequency in the original signal, but in practice, you should oversample at least ten times as fast as the highest frequency.  So set the bandwidth to at least ten times the frequency of your highest step rate.  I wouldn't use the "delay" function in the code; instead, set the accelerometer's output data rate and interrupt the processor on each data point.  This lets the accelerometer itself set the sample rate and keeps you on time regardless of the time to execute your firmware (as long as it's not too long!)  The accelerometer hardware automatically adjusts a digital antialiasing filter to match the data rate, so you don't have to worry about Nyquist.

With a fixed data rate, the differential value is then simply the output value minus the previous output value, which is basically the slope of the pulses on the red line you have shown.  The rising edge will give you a positive value, and the falling edge a negative one.  This also provides the advantage that a constant acceleration does not affect the output (gravity).

Good luck!

Comment: I know It's been a while since you suggest this. I finally have a time to implement ur suggest to my project. I can't use interrupt some how. It doesn't work with adxl345. `attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);` , `Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
Wire.write(0x2E); // Access the INT_ENABLE register (0x2E)
Wire.write(0x80); // Enable data-ready interrupt (bit 7)
Wire.endTransmission();` `Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
Wire.write(0x2F); // Access the INT_MAP register (0x2F)
Wire.write(0x00); // Map data-ready interrupt to INT1 pin (bit 0)
Wire.endTransmission();`

Comment: I try to implement like this but when I try to interrupt, it doesn't print anything. It prints for first 3 sample then it stops.